# Normal subgroups and functions from cosets to cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K ⊂ G$ be a normal subgroup and let $G/K$ be the set of left cosets of $K$.

Consider
the function
$G/K × G/K → G/K$ given by $(g1 · K, g2 · K) → (g1 · g2) · K$.

(a) Prove this function is well-defined.

(b) Prove this function makes $G/K$ a group.

What does it mean for the function to be well defined in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has cosets as domain, but the definition is written using *representatives* of the cosets ($g_1$ and $g_2$ in this case). When writing it that way, there is always the danger of the function taking *different values* on the *same cosets* if you choose a different representative. Such a function would not be well-defined.

Showing that the function is well-defined means showing that choosing different representatives for the same cosets as input to the function gives the same coset as output.

To show what I mean, here is a function which is not well-defined. Take $f:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Z$ defined by $f(a/b) = a+b$. Then $f(1/1) = 2$, but $f(2/2) = 4$. The fractions $\frac11$ and $\frac22$ represent the same rational number, but give different function values. Thus $f$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Could you explain how to go about proving this for this example?

Comment: @childishsadbino A literal translation of my second paragraph into a concrete algebraic exercise would be this: Take $g_1, g_2, h_1, h_2\in G$ such that $g_1K = h_1K$ and $g_2K = h_2K$ (i.e. choose different representatives for the same cosets). Then show that $(g_1g_2)K = (h_1h_2)K$ (i.e. that you get the same coset).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to prove this from the definition of the normal subgroup K!

Comment: I am still unsure on how to prove the function makes G/K a group because I am unable to prove the inverse exists in G/K as well.

Comment: @childishsadbino That's as simple as it can be. $(gK)^{-1} = (g^{-1})K$.